# How to move UIView Animation to background?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

The idea is to have rotating images on a dashboard with 4 or 5 bars for links. The uiviews for the links are working and the animation for the uiview is working and before I add the animation into the app everything is fine, the layer for the animation is on teh back. Now when I add the code for the image rotations, it puts the animated images on top of the other layers instead of staying at the back.

I have this code setup in my viewcontroller.m file and it's working as intended. Although the issue I'm having is that the UIView is being drawn on top of the others even though it's on the bottom

// Rotating Images on dash

```
    UIImageView *rotateImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:88];
    rotateImage.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"c3_1.jpg"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"c3_5.jpg"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"c3_7.jpg"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"c3_8.jpg"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"c3_10.jpg"], nil];

    // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
    rotateImage.animationDuration = 10.75;
    // repeat the annimation forever
    rotateImage.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    // start animating
    [rotateImage startAnimating];
    // add the animation view to the main window
    [self.view addSubview:rotateImage];
```

**For those that have this issue it was easy fix.. :)

lol.. it was staring me right in the face..

adding the subview at the end was putting it on top of the stack. removed that line and it's working proper now.

Comment: Please leave your edit as an answer and accept it so that others know that this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

It was staring me in the face. Adding the subview at the end was putting it on top of the stack.

So I added this as the next line.

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:rotateImage];